# What does signing drivers / modules do and what is the significance?

Tags: drivers, proprietary-drivers, secure-boot

Having recently installed a driver which required for the module to be signed manually it was confusing what signing that module was actually doing and why it had to be done.

There are other questions about the process on here however they are more technical.
What is a simple explanation of what signing modules does and why it is necessary as well as what the alternatives are (apparently dkms can automatically sign modules)?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel can be configured to either just warn you when unsigned or incorrectly signed modules are used (by a log message + by setting a taint flag on the kernel), or to outright reject any kernel modules that don't have a signature the kernel can validate.

When using BIOS-style boot process, or when using UEFI with Secure Boot disabled, this is essentially just an optional extra security procedure. It will make it somewhat harder for intruders to add evil kernel modules (like kernel-based rootkits, to hide the intruder's tools and actions) to the system.

But when using UEFI with Secure Boot enabled, it is part of Secure Boot requirements. The "spirit" of Secure Boot is to disallow loading of untrusted code into kernel space. The UEFI firmware checks for the presence of valid signature (or a whitelisted SHA256 hash) on the bootloader; the bootloader is required to check for the same on the OS kernel; and the kernel is supposed to extend this requirement to all code that is going to be executed in kernel space.

Of course, in practice the OS kernel can easily opt out of this requirement. But the organizations that developed Secure Boot have decided that this opting out should at least require a definite action from the system administrator: the default should be to enforce the signature requirement.

(By the way, this is also part of the reason why modern Windows requires any installed drivers to be signed by default. If you want to install unsigned drivers, you need to explicitly change a setting that requires administrator access.)

A tool that would be bootable on a Secure Boot system and allow execution of unsigned kernel-space code "out of the box" would be called a *Secure Boot circumvention device* and would be classifiable as malware.

Microsoft is the most well-known Secure Boot signer, and they will only sign versions of the `shimx64.efi` shim bootloader that will enforce the signature requirement.

A Secure Boot aware UEFI firmware will have built-in ability to check signatures on binaries that use the Microsoft PE+ binary format, which is what the `*.efi` files use. But the Linux world does not generally use that binary format: the ELF binary format is used instead.

Both Linux kernel modules and GNU GRUB bootloader modules are based on the ELF format. This requires the bootloader and the kernel to supply their own signature checking algorithms for ELF binaries, but apparently the UEFI Forum (the industry consortium that manages the UEFI and Secure Boot specifications) has decided that it's OK to do that as long as the default requirement for valid signatures is maintained.

Of course this does not quite work out as expected if you use DKMS to automatically build and sign kernel modules: it means there will be a certificate with its private key present which can be used to automatically produce a valid signature, so an intruder can also use it to sign any evil kernel modules too. It's not less secure than a system with no Secure Boot, but not much more secure either.

If you have multiple systems, you could get some security benefit from having the private key for your module signing certificate only on one host (presumably the one that is least threatened by attackers), and using that to build any custom kernels and/or modules you might need, and distributing them from there to any other hosts that need them. That way, the other hosts would only need the public part of the module signing certificate, which can only be used to validate existing signatures, not to create new ones.